# React complains that hook is not used inside of a body function when my component is passed into another component to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that uses another component as a renderer. However, React doesn't allow me to use hooks in the renderer component as it throws the following error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

Here's an example of what I have in my display component *which is an error boundary*:

```
class DisplayComponent extends Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    const { rendererComponent } = this.props;
    return rendererComponent({ enabled: true, name: 'hello-world' })
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `rendererComponent` prop in the `DisplayComponent` is called as a function though it's a component and I pass in some props into it as I call it this way.

Now, in my other file where I use the `DisplayComponent`, it looks something like this:

```
const RendererComponent = (props) => {
  const { enabled, name } = props;

  const [testState, setTestState] = useState(); // Error: Invalid hook call

  useEffect(() => {
    // Error: Invalid hook call
  }, [testState]);

  return (
    <div>{name} - {enabled}</div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <DisplayComponent rendererComponent={RendererComponent} />
  )
}
```

Here's the key thing. For some reason, I can't use hooks such as `useEffect`, `useState`, etc in the `RendererComponent`. If I use it, React will throw the error I mentioned above that the hook is invalid. But I would like to have some logic which requires hooks in the `RendererComponent`.

How can I use hooks to have states and effects in a component that is called the way I did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a **function call** instead of **mounting** the component, those are two different calls and syntax, change it to:

```
class DisplayComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    // Custom component must be Capitalized
    const { rendererComponent: RenderedComponent } = this.props;
    return <RenderedComponent enabled name="hello-world" />;
  }
}

// Notice that the JSX is transpiled to
React.createElement(RenderedComponent, {
  enabled: true,
  name: "hello-world"
});
```

In React, you can only mount a component by calling its API with `React.createElement` (JSX is its sugar syntax), while a simple function call is purely JS which does not trigger React API i.e won't register the component to the component tree. Therefore inner implementation like hooks has no meaning, you will lose state on every render (the Reconciliation won't be triggered).

Comment: Ohh... Somehow, calling it as a function works as the component gets rendered on the screen when I don’t have hooks in it? What’s the difference and use case between the 2 different ways of calling the components?

Comment: Added a bit of explanation hope it helps.